# sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command:

Tags: sed, scripting

Could someone tell me what does this reply mean ?

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `
'
```

I get it when I use :

```
sed -n "$num"p $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_sql.txt
for i in `seq 5 $max`
do
    lineNum=$(($num + $i))
    echo $lineNum
    sed -n "$lineNum"p $javaFile >> ~/Desktop/$1_sql.txt
done
```

Where $javaFile is a java file and num is an integer.

Comment: Looks like `$num` contains a newline character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is OK. It's the line terminator making it doesn't work, probably. You can check the line terminator with

```
file YourScriptFile
```

If it returns something like "...with CRLF line terminators", You can change CRLF to LF line terminator by using

```
flip -u YourScriptFile
```

Run the script file again.

P.S.
There is a quick and dirty solution to your problem

```
cut -d $'\n' -s -f ${num},$((num+5))-$((num+max)) $javaFile
```

`-d $'\n'` means we are using `\n` as delimiter and `-f ${num},$((num+5))-$((num+max))` means the fields (in this situation, lines) you want. Fields are a list, which can be `1-3`, `1,3-10` etc.