# `sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command:` but the line endings are fine

Tags: shell, sed

I want to remove the line that contains `set -x` in the file `"$(which tsc)", but I get an error:

```
$ sed -i ".bak" 'set -x' "$(which tsc)"
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.'
```

I checked [the solution here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163847/sed-e-expression-1-char-4-unknown-command), but my line terminators are `LF`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have syntactic error. There can't be any space after `-i`, just the extension; this is the source of the (initial) error message.

Also, to remove a line based on a pattern you need `/<pattern>/ d` with `sed` (there are other approaches but this one is the cleanest). So do:

```
sed -i".bak" '/set -x/ d' "$(which tsc)"
```

Optionally, as the backup extension does not contain any whitespace or control characters, you could get away without quoting in this case:

```
sed -i.bak '/set -x/ d' "$(which tsc)"
```

Comment: You also have to remove the space after the `-i`.

Comment: Old versions of `sed` do not accept whitespace in between the pattern and the `d`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sed -i.bak '/pattern to match/d' ./infile
```

Also you can refer to [Delete lines in a text file that containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/delete-lines-in-a-text-file-that-containing-a-specific-string) (on Stack Overflow) for more methods to delete lines which contain `set -x`.